Conceptual question regarding the Fokker-Planck equation and boundary conditions
Suppose I've been given the following differential equation
$$\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial J(x,t)}{\partial x}=0$$
where, $$J(x,t)=-p(x,t)\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x} + D \frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial x}$$
It has been claimed that at a distant future time, the system would approach a steady state, where $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = 0$, and the solution is given as follows,
$$p(x,t\rightarrow\infty) \approx \exp(-V(x)/D)$$
I need to solve this PDE numerically, for a given potential and parameters. I've used the finite difference method.
My question is related to the boundary conditions for this differential equation. Suppose, I set the boundary conditions of the following form $p(x_0,0) = p(x_l,0) = k$(say). The obvious problem here is after a long time, these boundary values no longer correspond to the steady state solution values at the same point. Does it mean that this type of boundary condition is invalid if we want to reach the steady state.
Should we instead specify the derivative of the distribution at the boundaries ?
Moreover, why is the previous boundary condition, where we specify the value of $p$ at the end points, inconsistent with the steady state solution ?

The boundary values at the initial condition need not match the boundary conditions for the PDE at $t>0$. Why do you think these boundary conditions should be invalid for the steady state solution?

Do I not need to fix my boundary conditions, if I'm coding this in python for example.

If this is a Fokker Planck equation, doesn’t the fact that the density integrates to 1 make the solution unique?

The steady state solution can be more complicated than that, unless I'm missing something... Assuming that $p = p(x)$ the equation becomes
$$
(-p(x) V'(x) + Dp'(x))' = 0 \Leftrightarrow p'(x) - \frac{V'(x)}{D} p(x) = \alpha
$$
Solving this linear differential equation, we get
$$
p(x) = e^{\int \frac 1D V'(x) dx}\left(C + \int \alpha e^{-\int \frac 1D V'(x) dx} dx \right) = C e^{\frac{V(x)}{D}} + \alpha e^{\frac 1D V(x)}\cdot \int e^{-\frac 1D V(x)}dx
$$
The constants $\alpha, C$ can be computed imposing boundary conditions that should hold for large $t$.
Take for instance $V(x)=x$ and $D=1$. The steady state solution is then $p(x)=- \alpha + c e^x$, which can accommodate the boundary conditions you see fit.
